# Can not run lua script from Fceux emulator usnig torch

Tags: lua, emulation, ubuntu-16.04, torch

I am using Fceux 2.2.3 emulator and i am trying to run a lua script using torch while playing super mario bros. When i load the script i face this error

> Lua thread bombed out: error loading module 'libpaths' from file
>   '/home/antonis/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so':
>     /home/antonis/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so: undefined
>   symbol: lua_gettop

I looked in the specific folder in the path and the libpaths.so is there.
What this error means?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build tha latest FCEUX from source (https://github.com/TASVideos/fceux) using the option to use system libraries. Then you specify LuaJIT (install it first) in the SContruct file and install. After that, install torch on your system. It will be available to FCEUX through "require 'torch'". That is the way I did it (right now, tbh), but you could probably install Torch first and then link its own LuaJIT files to FCEUX.